# req.body not working when using multipart/form-data in html form NodeJs/Express

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

I am using `body-parser` to get info requested from forms, but when I put `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the header of the form, the `req.body` will not working at all.

However, I have used `multer` lib in order to upload images as follow:

```
app.post("/", function (req, res, next) {
  var button = req.body.button_name;
  if (button == "upload") {
    var UserId = 2;
    var imageUploadedLimited = 3;
    var storage = multer.diskStorage({
      destination: function (req, file, callback) {
        var dir = "./public/images/uploads/";
        if (!fs.existsSync(dir)) {
          fs.mkdirSync(dir);
        }
        dir = "./public/images/uploads/" + UserId;
        if (!fs.existsSync(dir)) {
          fs.mkdirSync(dir);
        }
        callback(null, dir);
      },
      filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.fieldname + "-" + Date.now() + ".jpg");
      },
    });
    const maxSize = 1 * 1000 * 1000;

    var upload = multer({
      storage: storage,
      limits: { fileSize: maxSize },
      fileFilter: function (req, file, cb) {
        var filetypes = /jpeg|jpg|png/;
        var mimetype = filetypes.test(file.mimetype);

        var extname = filetypes.test(
          path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase()
        );

        if (mimetype && extname) {
          return cb(null, true);
        }

        cb(
          "Error: File upload only supports the " +
            "following filetypes - " +
            filetypes
        );
      },
    }).array("filename2", imageUploadedLimited);

    upload(req, res, function (err) {
      if (err) {
        res.send(err);
      } else {
        res.send("Success, Image uploaded!");
      }
    });
  }
});
```

If I print out the `button` variable from the second line, will show me `undefined` value. I know `body-parser` does not support `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. In this case, how I can see the value from the form?

Comment: you might want to go through `multiparty` documentation on https://www.npmjs.com/package/multiparty#readme

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using multer, it needs to be passed as middleware

```
// Do Something like this
var multer  = require('multer')
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, 'Your path here')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, "fileName")
    }
})
var upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
})

app.post("/" ,upload.any(), function (req, res, next) {
    // NOW YOU CAN ACCESS REQ BODY HERE
});
```