# Upload image using form data Multer NPM package

Tags: node.js, express, postman, multer

I have Node Express Post endpoint `http://localhost:3000/image/upload` for uploading images using form data.

Code for this is `imagectrl.js`:

```
const logger = require("../shared/winstonconfig").loggerObject.logger;
    const multer = require("multer");
    const upload = multer({ dest: "uploads/" });
    
    module.exports = function (app) {
      app.post("/image/upload", upload.array("image", 1), function (
        req,
        resp,
        next
      ) {
        resp.send({ image: req.file });
      });
    };
```

`App.js`:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyparser = require("body-parser");
const logger = require("./shared/winstonconfig").loggerObject.logger;
const app = express();

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  next();
});

app.use(
  bodyparser.urlencoded({
    extended: false,
  })
);
app.use(bodyparser.json());

app.listen(3000);
const dbconfig = require("./db/dbconfig");
logger.info("Express Server started succesfully.");
const controllers = require("./controller/imagectrl")(app);
```

I am using Postman to send the image to the above endpoint:

[image: PostMan Screenshot]

I always get null response from Express and the image file is also not getting stored on disk. What might be the issue here?

I am not passing this header in Postman. `headerContent-Type: {multipart/form-data}`

How can we log form data request in Node?

Comment: try console req.body and try this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62213070/req-body-not-working-when-using-multipart-form-data-in-html-form-nodejs-express/62213797#62213797

Comment: Thanks for comment. I used workaround to use web socket to process images.

Comment: Ohh wait ! you are gonna use sockets for images?